# Emulator doesn't give Error but Device gives java.lang.NullPointerException on putExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I have a big problem please someone help me please.

I have an ActionBar with Tabs and 3 Fragments.

In `onCreateView` method i have this:

*MainActivity.java*

```
...

@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = null;
            TextView textView;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ResultActivity.class);


            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)  == 1){
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);



                Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.procura_ingredientes);
                final EditText ing_1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_1);
                final EditText ing_2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_2);


                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        intent.putExtra(MOD_SEARCH,1);

                        String ingredient_1 = ing_1.getText().toString();
                        String ingredient_2 = ing_2.getText().toString();

                        if(ingredient_1.length() <= 0) ingredient_1 = "";
                        if(ingredient_2.length() <= 0) ingredient_2 = "";

                        intent.putExtra("ingredient_1",ingredient_1);
                        intent.putExtra("ingredient_2",ingredient_2);

                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });


            }else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2){
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
                GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                final ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
                gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

                gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity()," " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        long cat = imageAdapter.getItemId(position);
                        if(cat <= 0) cat = 1;
                        intent.putExtra(MOD_SEARCH,2);
                        intent.putExtra("cat_id",cat);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });



            }else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

                final EditText editText = (EditText)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_search_term);
                Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_recipe_search);

                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        int cont = editText.getText().toString().length();
                        if (cont < 2) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                            dialog.setTitle("Atenção");
                            dialog.setMessage("O nome da receita precisa ter mais de " + cont + " letras ");

                            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            dialog.show();
                        } else {
                        intent.putExtra(MOD_SEARCH,0);
                        String recipe = editText.getText().toString();
                        if(recipe.length() <= 0) recipe = "";
                        intent.putExtra("recipe_name",recipe);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return rootView;
           /* textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));*/

        }
    }
```

If you look you see

```
if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)  == 1){

}else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2){

else
```

this manage what tab user are in, all go to same ResultActivity but pass diferent ExtraStrings,

```
intent.putExtra(MOD_SEARCH,0);
intent.putExtra(MOD_SEARCH,1);
intent.putExtra(MOD_SEARCH,2);
```

the MOD_SEARCH control what Result was execute.

*ResultActivity.java*

```
public static final String MOD_SEARCH = null;
mode  = getIntent().getIntExtra(MOD_SEARCH,0);

    if(mode == 0){ ..
     }else if(mode == 1) ..
    }else if(mode == 2) ..
```

---

So, in emulator it works fine all, when i click in in each fragment it shows me the correct information.

After publishing app to  Google Play few days ago and i get this errors:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.Intent.putExtra(Intent.java:5558)
at com.iondev.cozinhaparasolteiros.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:256)
```

and

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.Intent.putExtra(Intent.java:5325)
at com.iondev.cozinhaparasolteiros.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:226)
```

I dont understand because in emulator it works without error and device have error, i don't know what is wrong, please someone have a suggestion, need repair because are in store.

Comment: what is line 226 `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: is intent.putExtra(MOD_SEARCH,2); thanks much, i need declare that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
public static final String MOD_SEARCH = null;
```

for this

```
public static String MOD_SEARCH = "";
```

I think your problem is with the word "final" as initializing the variable with "null" being kind "final" will not be able to change its value later, so to assign to the Intent is Null.

I hope you serve.

Sorry for my low level of English.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized Intent any where in your code because it giving NullPointerException here..

```
intent.putExtra(MOD_SEARCH,2);
intent.putExtra("cat_id",cat);
```

take it as local and initilize where ever you want..